# How do I access the pixels of an SDL 2 texture?

Tags: sdl, pixel

How exactly can one get to the RGBA pixel arrays of SDL 2.0 textures? Does the texture need to be specially initialized and locked down?

Comment: Texture needs to be created with SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, See SDL_LockTexture, SDL_UnlockTexture.

Answer (score 3):

Call [`SDL_LockTexture` to get the data](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture) and [`SDL_UnlockTexture` when you are finished](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UnlockTexture):

```
byte * bytes= nullptr;
int pitch = 0;
SDL_LockTexture(texturePointer, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&bytes), &pitch);

// ...read data...

SDL_UnlockTexture(texturePointer);
```

Both methods have return codes you should check for errors, obviously.

The `bytes` pointer will refer to the locked bits of the texture, and the `pitch` variable will contain the number of bytes between successive rows of a texture (to account for padding).

Note that the texture must have been created with the streaming access flag (`SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING`).

Also note that you get the raw bytes of the texture data, which may not always be RGBA (for example, the texture may not have alpha).

Comment: `you get the raw bytes of the texture data` Per the API docs, you don't! https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture - `As an optimization, the pixels made available for editing don't necessarily contain the old texture data. This is a write-only operation, and if you need to keep a copy of the texture data you should do that at the application level.` It's hard to think of a way this restriction could actually be implemented, but still seems dodgy to rely on something they explicitly don't guarantee. I worry that folk doing this somehow risk the client code breaking one day, when it'd be too late